# ASP.NET Core send Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on failed authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, authorization, asp.net-core-3.0

I have both CORS and authorization setup on my controller. When the client is authenticated and sends a valid `Authorization` header, everything works fine. If the client sends an invalid `Authorization` header or no header at all, the response from the server is a 401 without an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header which causes a lot of issues on the client.

Is there a way to force asp.net core to always send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header even if the authorization fails?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use CORS before using authorization.

**Not Working**

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

if (env.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .WithOrigins("https://example.com")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
}
```

**Working**

```cs
if (env.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .WithOrigins("https://example.com")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
}

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```